# forward from servlet in higher directory to jsp in subfolder

Tags: jsp, servlets, forwarding

i have

```
root/logged/form.jsp
root/servlet
root/logged/form.jsp
```

I have jsp page `logged/form.jsp` this submits form to servlet `action="../update"`. Now i want to add some parameters to request and forward it to `logged/form.jsp` but its not working and showing me form.jsp in root context only `root/servlet`. Please help what url should i forward my request to. I cannot use sendRedirect as has to retain request object.

I have tried with forward(`logged/form.jsp`) and forward(`/logged/form.jsp`) and forward(`/form.jsp`) in my servlet

Comment: To clear things up: do you have one WAR (ROOT) or two WAR's (ROOT and logged)? And which appserver are you using? Tomcat 6?

Comment: I have root/logged (logged as subfolder of my root war).
Using tomcat6

Comment: I had all JSPs in single root war but then i moved some jsps tp sub folder logged and made changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try always using absolute paths (starting with a / ) which are interpreted as relative to the context root.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The `/logged/form.jsp` ought to be the right one. I suggest to read the appserver logs. Big chance that there's an `IllegalStateException: response already committed` inside.</strike>

Wait, wait, your actual problem is thus that you want to change the URL which the visitor sees in the address bar?

If so, then no, that isn't possible with a forward. I'd then suggest to solve the problem from the other side on. Just "hide" `form.jsp` in the `/WEB-INF` folder and use a servlet all the time to get/post the form.

Pseudo:

```
protected void doGet(request, response) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/logged/form.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(request, response) {
    doYourSubmitThingHere();
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/logged/form.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

map this servlet on an `url-pattern` of `/logged/form`, replace the `<form method="post" action="/servlet">` by `<form method="post" action="/logged/form">` and then you can use/invoke it by `http://example.com/logged/form`.

You can also go a step further by adopting the page controller pattern and make use of `HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()` to obtain the request path (and the JSP file's path) so that you don't need to boil a new servlet for every JSP.

Comment: why to put logged folder in web-inf.I am not getting desired o/p with this. say from http://example.com/index.html when logged in i want to go to http://example.com/looged/form.jsp which submits form to servlet(http://example.com/servlet) and then it is forwaded back to http://example.com/looged/form.jsp  what is the best way to that. I moved form.jsp from my root directoty to "logged" folder in my root dir. but my forwarding back to form.jsp from servlet is not working.  forward("/looged/form.jsp")

Answer (score 0):

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("../ïndex.jsp").forward(req,resp);
```